# Regex should handle whitespace including newline differently

Tags: python, html, regex

My goal is to make a regex that can handle 2 situations:

- Multiple whitespace including one or more newlines in any order should become a single newline
- Multiple whitespace excluding any newline should become a space

The unorderedness combined with the different cases for newline and no newline is what makes this complex.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

E.g.

```
'   \n \n \n a'     # --> '\na'
'   \t \t    a'     # --> ' a'  
'   \na\n     '     # --> '\na\n'
```

Benchmark:

```
s = '   \n \n \n a   \t \t    a   \na\n     '
n_times = 1000000
------------------------------------------------------
change_whitespace(s)   - 5.87 s
change_whitespace_2(s) - 3.51 s
change_whitespace_3(s) - 3.93 s

n_times = 100000
------------------------------------------------------
change_whitespace(s * 100)    - 27.9 s 
change_whitespace_2(s * 100)  - 16.8 s 
change_whitespace_3(s * 100)  - 19.7 s
```

Comment: Ridiculous. How is this too broad of a question?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you didn't show what you'd tried, but that doesn't necessarily make it too broad per se, so I don't know.

Comment: A nice question, I also thought about 2-step approach, but did not have access to a PC. Please do not forget to accept answers that worked for you :)

Answer (score 2):

*(Assumes Python can do regex replace with callback function)*

You could use some callback to see what the replacement needs to be.
Group 1 matches, replace with space.
Group 2 matches, replace with newline

`(?<!\s)(?:([^\S\r\n]+)|(\s+))(?!\s)`

```
 (?<! \s )           # No whitespace behind
 (?:
      ( [^\S\r\n]+ )      # (1), Non-linebreak whitespace
   |  
      ( \s+ )             # (2), At least 1 linebreak
 )
 (?! \s )            # No whitespace ahead
```

Comment: Very nice, like @TigerhawkT3 suggested. I'm surprised he didn't +1 you. I'll accept his answer since it is the Python answer, but he surely owes +1.

Comment: I'm no regexpert, so it'll take some more study before I understand the technique in this answer.

Comment: For a replace function its simple `(?<!\s)(?:([^\S\r\n]+)|\s+)(?!\s)` if matched group(1) replace with space, else newline... Don't know Python.

Comment: Oh, I see - I was doing the inverse and checking for `group(0)` matches, but it's the second group that may or may not match.

Comment: Only group 1 or 2 will match (not both), only need to check if a single group matched.

Comment: Now I see there are three groups in there, so I needed to check either `group(1)` or `group(2)`, not `group(0)`... doh. Anyway, thanks for the expression and explanation; upvoted. :)

Answer (score 1):

This replaces the whitespace that contains a newline with a single newline, then replaces the whitespace that doesn't contain a newline with a single space.

```
import re

def change_whitespace(string):
    return re.sub('[ \t\f\v]+', ' ', re.sub('[\s]*[\n\r]+[\s]*', '\n', string))
```

Results:

```
>>> change_whitespace('   \n \n \n a')
'\na'
>>> change_whitespace('   \t \t    a')
' a'
>>> change_whitespace('   \na\n     ')
'\na\n'
```

Thanks to @sln for reminding me of regex callback functions:

```
def change_whitespace_2(string):
    return re.sub('\s+', lambda x: '\n' if '\n' in x.group(0) else ' ', string)
```

Results:

```
>>> change_whitespace_2('   \n \n \n a')
'\na'
>>> change_whitespace_2('   \t \t    a')
' a'
>>> change_whitespace_2('   \na\n     ')
'\na\n'
```

And here's a function with @sln's expression:

```
def change_whitespace_3(string):
    return re.sub('(?<!\s)(?:([^\S\r\n]+)|(\s+))(?!\s)', lambda x: ' ' if x.group(1) else '\n', string)
```

Results:

```
>>> change_whitespace_3('   \n \n \n a')
'\na'
>>> change_whitespace_3('   \t \t    a')
' a'
>>> change_whitespace_3('   \na\n     ')
'\na\n'
```

Comment: The callback one is significantly faster! Didn't know the second argument could be a function.

Comment: `if '\n' in x.group(0)` suspiciously looks like rescanning the same stuff.

Comment: Second version is faster though (and still correct). Test string is all 3 examples concatenated, ran 1 milllion times.

Comment: How about the third version?

Comment: Those are interesting timing results. I guess the two small checks are faster than the single larger check.